# Is there a media player that sorts WMA in track order?

Tags: media-player, wma

I'm using an HTC Desire with 2.2 and the stock media player annoyingly sorts the tracks in alphabetical order.  According to MediaMonkey the files have the correct track order tag in them.

Is there a media player that sorts the tracks correctly? (I've also tried Winamp and btunes at this point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4620) that disallows sorting of WMA files by track number.

You could try using MediaMonkey or something like MP3Tag on your PC to rename the file as
`%track_number% - %Artist% - %Title%.wma` or something similar, so it sorts by name.

Also try [Meridian Player](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.iii.romulus.meridian&feature=search_result) - you can create a PlayQ (kinda like a playlist and then sort that by Track, I believe.

And be sure to take a look @ [Mort Player](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.stohelit.folderplayer) too.

Comment: Thanks Sparx, a shame but good to know it's a bug.

Comment: Thanks again - Mort Player will play the tracks in the right order, so that works around it until the bug gets fixed...